# How to use caller command to only return line number in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Newbie question, but hopefully someone can help.

I'm writing a function in a bash script that has error checking built in. I'd like to return an error message contining the line number, e.g.

`Error, parameter not provided, please check line 57`

I've found the `caller` command, but this returns

`57 filename.sh`

I've thought of using regex to extract only the numbers, but that seems like overkill, and the caller command itself doesn't seem to have an option to return only the line number.

Is there a way in bash to only return what I want?

Note the call may be on line 50, 500 or 5000, so a get from left x character won't work.

Comment: Maybe variable `BASH_LINENO` is all you need? The first array element contains the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `caller` instruction in `bash` returns two space separated values: the line number and file name of the caller. For example,

```
57 filename.sh
```

All you need here is to pick out the first parameter, and `awk` can do that very easily:

```
caller | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Result

```
57
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `help caller` text, the first word of the returned text is the line number.

We can use the bash read command to split it into words:

```bash
read lineno rest <<< "$(caller)"
```

Using a regex is not so onerous

```bash
[[ $(caller) =~ ^([[:digit:]]+) ]] && lineno=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

---

```bash
#!/bin/bash
                                          # line 2
a() { b; }                                # line 3
b() { c; }                                # line 4
c() {                                     # line 5
    caller                                # line 6
    out=$(caller); echo "$out"            # line 7
    i=0                                   # line 8
    while true; do                        # line 9
        c=$(caller $i)                    # line 10
        [[ -z "$c" ]] && break            # line 11
        printf '%d = %s\n' $((i++)) "$c"  # line 12
    done                                  # line 13
}                                         # line 14
a                                         # line 15
```

outputs

```
4 caller.sh
4 caller.sh
0 = 4 b caller.sh
1 = 3 a caller.sh
2 = 15 main caller.sh
```